# Querying SQL server using windows authentication from a local admin account

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying to query MS SQL Server from a client with below connection string.

```
connStr='Driver={SQL Server};Server=Svr1;Database=testDB;User Id=DOMAIN1\User1;Password=test123;'
```

When I logged in to the client as a domain user, say DOMAIN1\User2 it works fine.
But in production environment, my script will be running as a service under admin account. Hence, when I try to execute the same script when logged in as local admin in same client machine, I get the below error

```
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('28000', '[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (18452) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication. (18452); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute (0)')
```

When I search for this error, many of the solutions are related to password expiry cases. Is there some attribute I can add to connection string to make this query work? I tried adding IntegratedSecurity=False, but it didn't work.

I am trying to access SQL Server 14.0.2027.2 using Python PyODBC module.

Comment: There's no problem with admin accounts. The error is clear and the solution is to actually **NOT** use an admin account in production, or development. Would you run a daemon as `root` in Linux? Create a domain *service* account and use it for your service

Comment: BTW the error has nothing to do with password expiration. If you googled for this exact error one of the first if not the very first result [would be this one about loopback checks and Kerberos](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2017/04/18/sql-server-login-failed-login-untrusted-domain-cannot-used-windows-authentication/). It's better to create a service account with just the permissions you need for the service to work

Comment: You can use [managed service accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/group-managed-service-accounts-overview) to have the OS automatically manage passwords, removing the need to protect and renew them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Due to our company policy, it is not straight forward to create a domain service account. Also, the service will be run as "SYSTEM" and not "Administrator". But I assume both "SYSTEM" and "ADMINISTRATOR" are local accounts and won't be able to access the SQL server

Comment: That's no excuse for allowing hijack of the local machine. That's what using `Administrator` or `System` means.  DON'T use those accounts. you don't need those permissions. You can create local service accounts. There are even local *managed* service accounts you could use. The IIS Application pool accounts are one example. This will work provided the SQL Server database is installed on the same machine

Comment: If the database is remote, you *need* a domain account. The database server simply doesn't know and doesn't trust the local accounts created by other machines. You would't want a hacker to just connect to your machine by using his/her own `Administrator` account after all. The alternative is to use SQL Server accounts instead of Windows authentication, include the credentials in the connection string and take care to ensure that connection string doesn't leak. Which involves *not* allowing any service to run with elevated privileges, that would allow it to read any config file on the machine

Comment: In any case, local accounts work, even admin accounts. You don't need to disable Windows Authentication. You just need to use the correct accounts for your case: local accounts for a local server, domain accounts for a remote server, all of them should have as few privileges as possible.

Comment: Will check with our IT for enabling running service as domain user. Else, I shall go with SQL server account with Mixed Mode authentication. Thanks for the clarification